# Is there a way to access the D-pad when developing android apps on flip phones?

Tags: android, mobile, d-pad

I am planning on buying a Japanese flip phone and want to make a soundcloud client for it. It should be running Android 8 but I don't know how to access the D-PAD for the phone to affect features within the application.

I have yet to get the phone, but I can't find anything related to D-PADs within android development for flip phone, only controller support and Android TV support. Are they each called as the same thing?

Comment: A D-pad generates keypresses, akin to arrow keys. See `KeyEvent` and so on.